# Is it possible to move border-bottom left or right in a list?

Tags: css, html-lists, border

I have `border-bottom` on my  `li`'s but I have `padding-left:10px` on my `ul` so it nudges everything to the right by 10px.

I'm wondering if its possible to knock the border back over to the left? or is this not possible as the border is a part of the `ul`?

html

```
<ul class="menuoptions">
<li>Home</li>

<li>Firewalls</li>

<li>SSL VPN Encryption</li>

<li>Security In Education</li>

<li>Wireless Access Points</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menuoptions {
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    width:225px;
    color:#666;
    line-height:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    top:10px;
    list-style:none;

}

.menuoptions li {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;       
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdu6E/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying this padding to your `ul` but not to the `li` elements. Firstly you need to reset the padding of the `ul` to 0 (as most browsers apply `padding-left` to the `ul` element by default):

```css
.menuoptions {
    ...
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then give the `padding-left` to your `li` elements:

```css
.menuoptions li {
    ...
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdu6E/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It is a part of the ul, however you could use margin-left:10px instead of padding (as long as it is a block element) and remove that part of the border.